# A counterexample to "If $b\neq 0$ and $ab$ are both central, then $a$ is central."

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with center $\mathrm{Z}(R)$. Assume that $a, b\in R$ such that $ab\in\mathrm{Z}(R)$ and $b\in\mathrm{Z}(R)\setminus\{0\}$. I would like to ask if $a\in\mathrm{Z}(R)$.

With the assumption: "$R$ has no zero divisors", if $r\in R$, then $(ra)b=r(ab)=(ab)r=a(br)=a(rb)=(ar)b$, which implies $ra=ar$, and thus $a\in\mathrm{Z}(R)$.

Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: For a prime ring, yes, as you said - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504053/let-r-be-a-prime-ring-then-ab-a-in-zr-implies-b-in-zr). Did you try a counterexample?

Comment: Oh, great for prime rings, I do not find a counterexample.

Comment: @TranNamSon I've taken the liberty of improving the title for you.  Please note that "a question about <vague topic>" is, as a rule, an unacceptable choice for a title.  It's in your best interest to do something more specific, ideally a summary of the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a non-prime example, just build something that works.

For example, $F_2\langle a,b,c\rangle /(cb-bc, ba,ab)$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.

$b$ is nonzero central, $a$ is nonzero noncentral (it does not commute with $c$), and $ab=0$ is central.

Comment: That is great. Thank you very much.